# Can someone please explain the best way to circumvent the same origin policy when using dashcode? I'm lost

Tags: javascript, ajax, same-origin-policy, dashcode

I've been reading all the suggestions on [Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy), but I don't know which one would be most successful when using dashcode, or even how to implement it.  Can anyone help?

Comment: Don't know much about dashcode, but `JSONP` is the easiest to understand and implement.

Comment: Are you writing a Mac Widget or an app?

Answer (score 2):

I've not used these solutions myself, but I'd suggest using either [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/#cross-origin-request) ([tutorial](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/05/25/cross-domain-ajax-with-cross-origin-resource-sharing/)) or [JSONP](http://www.json-p.org/) ([simpler](http://niryariv.wordpress.com/2009/05/05/jsonp-quickly/) and [more in-depth](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-aj-jsonp1/) explanations).

If you want an easier solution, [Any Origin](http://anyorigin.com/) was mentioned in the thread you linked.

The fact that you are using dashcode should not affect your javascript.

Comment: Thanks for hyperlinking, WSkid.

Comment: So I'm trying to use any origin and I have everything set up, but I don't have any idea what to enter into the datasource url field in dashcode.  Any ideas?